# Gaussian noise definitions

Tags: noise, kalman-filters, homework

I have an exercise that asks for us to determine the model for a system that goes like this:

> A battery manufacturer for cars is studying  how their batteries behave. The measurements are influenced by gaussian noise with center in 0V and standard deviation equal to 3 Volts. Nominal value for the Battery voltage is 14V. Determine the model for the system, as well as initial values to implement a Kalman Filter (in matlab).

It is quite clear what we want done. But I don't really understand how the centered values for the gaussian distributions could be different, and so I have no idea how to treat it. It is most likely that I have some concepts wrong, can someone explain how to deal with a noise that has a mean value different to the nominal value of the object in analysis?

Comment: I'd guess what it means is that the sensor reads $r=V+n$, where $V$ is the true battery voltage and $n$ is a Gaussian RV with zero mean and standard deviation 3. You want to find $V$ but all you have is $r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text:

> The measurements are influenced by gaussian noise with center in 0V and standard deviation equal to 3 Volts.

simply means that the Gaussian noise has $\mu = 0$ (the mean is zero) and $\sigma = 3$ (the standard deviation is 3 volts).

> Determine the model for the system, as well as initial values to implement a Kalman Filter

Without more information, a Kalman filter seems like overkill.

As @MBaz says, one model you could use is:
$$
r = V + n
$$
which has no time-dependent component. Making a Kalman-amenable model out of this might look like:
$$
V_{k+1} = V_k + m_k\tag{1}
$$
$$
r_k = V_k + n_k\tag{2}
$$
and we'd use the 14V nominal voltage to say $V_0 = 14$.

However, we are given no information about $m_k$ - how the true voltage might vary. We might also want to augment the state (perhaps the variation if $V_k$ depends on the derivative of $V+k$?) and so include a state transition matrix in front of $V_k$ in (1). If we did augment the state, we'd also probably want to add an output matrix on (2).

---

> Could you give me an insight about the initial covariance? Can it be reached from the information given?

Generally, I choose the initial state covariance to be VERY large. This is because I am generally given zero information about what it should be, as in this case. In this case, "VERY" might mean 30 (ten standard deviations).

Comment: I believe the true voltage for this case does not vary, and so mk should be zero.

Comment: @avio11 : In that case,  I truly see zero reason for a Kalman filter. :-)  It just adds complexity where none is needed.

Comment: It was used as an introductory problem. To make students get used to it, I guess? Could you give me an insight about the initial covariance? Can it be reached from the information given? We are asked to implement a filter in matlab, so we need two initial conditions (initial voltage and initial covariance).

Comment: @avio11 Amended question.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help thus far. I guess I can keep going on my own now. Thanks a lot.